# Gracefully terminate/kill a job in Airflow

Tags: go, operating-system, airflow

I have an airflow task which calls a Golang executable file and it runs for about 2 or 3 hours. I tried to stop this DAG by clicking on Mark Success / Mark Failed. I observed that the connections that are made during the run in golang are not closed even though I have written the logic to close the connections when a signal from OS (SIGTERM / SIGKILL) comes.

My doubt is, whenever a task/DAG is marked sucess/failed while it is already running, Will the rest of the code in the golang logic runs OR it abruptly stops without terminating gracefully?

How would I handle this scenario? When dag is stopped, the connections made by the golang executable should be closed

Please suggest!

I tried writing a go routine and kept it in the main.go file.

Below is the logic :

```
go signalHandler()

func signalHandler() {
    gracefulStop := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(gracefulStop, syscall.SIGKILL, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGHUP,
        syscall.SIGQUIT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-gracefulStop
    closeConnections()

}
```

I expected that the connections will be closed after I set the DAG to success/failed. But I observed that this logic never executed.